# html form changing positions on resolution change

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ive been working on a login screen for my website lately

I made a form with position as fixed, but as screen resolution changes the position of not only the form, but also image changes, thus making them intersect and making them have the wrong look.

Qs: how can I keep my form in one position in different resolutions,

website: secret.nuky.tk

and heres the code:

```
#username{  
top: 50%;
left:55%;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -200px;
}
#password{
top: 56%;
left: 55%;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -200px;
}
img{
position: fixed;
top:25%;
left:56%;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -200px;
}
```

thankyou,

Comment: Since you don't provide the code in the question, it is not possible to assess, however use of percentages and not pixels, or ems will probably help. Please don't link to external websites in your question.

Comment: tha answer you are searching is simply css, fixed position is at it's name says, well, fixed, even with percentages it is going to look akward if you don't know what you are doing

Comment: No need to use fixed position I guess, and if you are using `fixed` position, then assign values `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0` to give it full height and width and keep it in the same place in all resolutions. For better answer, please provide your code

Comment: @Dragonthoughts sorry I fixed it

Comment: @Abinthaha added the code sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first remove all your

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 55%;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -200px;
```

from your css elements, and notice how it is still pretty, simply not centered, then put everything you want to center inside a `<div class='center'>` then style it like that (or with fixed, but do NOT use margin with pixels if you want to be responsive to all screen sizes)

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

translate(-50%, -50%) mean I want to shift my div 50% of **it's** height and width to the top and the right, so it's centered on the div center, and not on the upper-left corner as you figured out, and tried to prevent with negative margins

Comment: Hello thx for the reply, Centering the form works but when it comes to placing the password area below the username and especially the login button there is a problem. I tried using </br> and it kind of worked for the username and password but the login button was shifted to the left, i was wondering how I could adjust tje login to center again, and how I could adjust the vertical spacing.

Comment: @NukY oh yes, and the same happens for your image (and everything that hasn't the same width as the form) just add **text-align:center** to your .center div ;) for vertical spacing, you could just put one <br>, and add a margin (or only a margin-bottom) to your inputs ;)